# How many possible symbols and punctuations in a password?

Tags: passwords, hash, brute-force, rainbow-table

I want to compute the possible combinations of a password consists of 8 digits of: alphabetical letters (26), numbers (0-9), symbols and punctuations.

In order to compute this, I have to know the total no. of possible characters and raise this to the power of length of the password. However, I do not know how many possible symbols or punctuations are there? Can any one help with a reference if possible please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the character set/encoding you're working with.

If we consider ASCII then there are 95 printable characters in total (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters). This includes lowercase and uppercase letters, digits, punctuation, and special (but printable) characters.